# How to install npm under CloudPanel?

Tags: laravel, npm

I'm very sorry to ask this here, but I don't know where I could get some info.

I primarly develop Laravel, and I'm using DigitalOcean with CloudPanel... so I provisioned a virtual server using the Laravel 10 template.

Then I posted my project to Github from my development machine, and then clone the project into the production server.

Next I must do a `composer install` that works perfectly

And then a `npm build`, and here comes the problem. The virtual server doesn't come with `npm`, so I tried installing it with `sudo apt install npm`, it asks for my password, I provide it, and then it tells me `Sorry, user myuser is not allowed to execute '/usr/bin/apt install npm' as root on cloudpanel-for-xxxx`

I've been looking all day, and all the results I got are related tohow to deploy a node app on cloudpanel and the like.

Maybe my question should be: How do I deploy a Laravel 10 app into a cloudpanel?

Answer (score 1):

**Use NVM and install NodeJS** - https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm?tab=readme-ov-file#installing-and-updating

1. First login to your Cloud panel server using the site-user and password from the site you have created.
2. Then install NVM and logout and login again.
3. Now, install NodeJS v20 using `nvm install 20`.

Now you've successfully installed NodeJS in your Cloud panel server and you can start using the npm commands.